# Can I create a public key or private key from an image file?

Tags: openssl

Let's say I had an image file of a close friend of mine.
Is there a way we can create a public private key pair from an image?

Something like:

```
openssl rsa -in picture.png -out test.key
```

or similar.

My close friend implied it was possible, but I am very new to sysadmin'in.
I have to wonder if he is yanking my chain!

Answer (score 1):

The scientific approach would have been to actually try that...

Did it work ?

The OpenSSL command line option [`rsa -in filename`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-rsa.html) expects the file name argument to be a rsa key

So a random PNG image file might work (in a truly random way) but that is not likely IMHO

Comment: fails since it is expecting a private key. Not sure if there is a clear way to create a private key from a .png